# Breadcrumb menu not working properly in Typo3 7.6.6

Tags: typo3, breadcrumbs, typo3-7.6.x

I already searched the whole internet for a solution but didn't find the right answer, so here is my question:

I have been trying to introduce a breadcrumb menu inside my website. I've done this by writing the following HMENU:

```
lib.breadcrumb=COA
lib.breadcrumb {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
            special = rootline
            special.range = 1|-1

            includeNotInMenu = 1
            1 = TMENU
            1 {
                    # no unneccessary scripting.
                    1.noBlur = 1
                    # Current item should be unlinked
                    1.CUR = 1
                    1.target = _self
                    1.wrap = <div class="breadcrumb"> | </div>
                    1.NO {
                            stdWrap.field = title
                            ATagTitle.field = nav_title // title
                            linkWrap = ||*| &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp; |*|
                    }
                   # Current menu item is unlinked
                   1.CUR {
                            stdWrap.field = title
                            linkWrap = ||*| &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp; |*|
                            doNotLinkIt = 1
                   }
            }
      }
}
```

The menu is showing on the website so the wiring is working fine. But the problem is, despite all sites have the common root site *Home* in backend hierarchie, the root isn't shown at all sites. Here is an concrete example of two different sites with the same site hierarchie tree returning different breadcrumbs:

Backend-Site-Tree:

```
Home----Referenzen-----Vertriebsplattform
    \---Kompetenzen----Schnittstellentechnik
```

edit:

[image]

Breadcrumbs:

[image: Breadcrumb1]

[image: Breadcrumb2]

I searched for differences in site configuration, but negative report. I also reset caches multiple times.

Does anybode have a similar problem or have an idea what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Could you make a screenshot about your site tree? Or visualise it pls in a top-down format. I think the problem is may your range: 1 |-1 so it will start one level behind. Do you have the same template inclueded in Home? Are Referenz and Kopetenz on the same level under home? Is the Kompetenz may a Shortcut type?

Comment: Hi @András. Ty for your suggestions. The templates of Kompetenzen and Referenzen match. As you will see they are on the same level in the side tree. Unfortunately neither Kompetenzen nor Referenzen are of type shortcut. Both are of type standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of research I found the reason why the breadcrumb didn't appear properly.

All the sites on the second level of the hierarchie use the same template (another one than the home site). But those of them which didn't show Home as part of their breadcrumb also mistakenly included the template of the home site as basic template. This has to be a remnant of earlier stages of development :(

I don't know exactly why the breadcrumb menu was affected by this but the problem disappeared after fixing this dependency.

Anyways thanks for all your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

take this:

```
special = rootline
special.range = 1
```

Comment: Ty for your answer. But unfortunately the outcome is similar. The first part of the breadcrumb just gets cutted off. So it's like:

Referenzen >> Vertriebsplattform, 
Schnittstellentechnik

respectively.

Comment: i build the root / home hardcode in the typoscript.
here is a example: http://www.typo3-probleme.de/2015/04/22/typo3-tx_news-breadcrumb-menue-einbinden-1580/